# THREE SVG to MeshLine - Filling shapes

Tags: svg, three.js, aframe

I'm attempting to load SVGs that are already in the DOM into a THREE.js scene

This is an example of an SVG I have

[image: original]

And this is how it is showing in the scene

[image: how it shows]

I'm attempting to use THREE.SVGLoader and THREE.MeshLine to display the icons.

Here is the HTML for that SVG

```
<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" id="FiDownload" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21 15v4a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-4"></path><polyline points="7 10 12 15 17 10"></polyline><line x1="12" y1="15" x2="12" y2="3"></line></svg>
```

And this is how I'm doing it

```
    const loader = new THREE.SVGLoader()
    const svg = loader.parse(el.outerHTML)

    const material = new THREE.MeshLineMaterial({
        color: new AFRAME.THREE.Color(this.data.color),
        resolution: new AFRAME.THREE.Vector2 ( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ),
        sizeAttenuation: 0,
        lineWidth: 2,//this.data.lineWidth,
        opacity: 1,//this.data.opacity,
        transparent: true,
        //near: 0.1,
        //far: 1000
      });

    svg.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
        const shapes = path.toShapes(true);
        shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {
        const geometry = new AFRAME.THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
        const mesh = new AFRAME.THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.el.object3D.add(mesh)
        });
    });
```

I get the error:

> THREE.DirectGeometry: Faceless geometries are not supported.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the icon SVGs to render properly in THREE?

Answer (score 0):

I used a LineGeometry

```
    svg.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
        const shapes = path.toShapes(true);
        shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {

        //@ts-ignore
        const line = new AFRAME.THREE.MeshLine();
        const geometry = new AFRAME.THREE.Geometry();
        shape.extractPoints().shape.forEach(vec2 => {
            geometry.vertices.push(new AFRAME.THREE.Vector3(vec2.x, vec2.y, 0))
        })  
        line.setGeometry( geometry )
        const mesh = new AFRAME.THREE.Mesh(line.geometry, this.material)
        this._shapes.push(mesh)
        this.el.object3D.add(mesh)
        });
    });
```